# Should I use one Friedman test or two Kruskal-Wallis tests on small sample?

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test, friedman-test

I am looking at concentrations at 3 sites over 4 years, with 4 samples at each site. Because of the small number of samples, I believe I should use non-parametric statistical tests.

My question is: should I do a Friedman, or should I do 2 separate K-W tests, one for sig. differences between the sites and another for sig. differences over time?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? As far as i remember the mentioned methods are helpfull to compare different classifiers on different data sets. Is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am trying to assess spatial and temporal trends in heavy metal concentrations in mussel populations.  I have 4 samples from each of the three sites over a period of 4 years.

Comment: Ok but that doesn't sounds like a classification task for me... what is the output of your algorithm? Do you perform cross validation?